# How do i search for type in restfb java?

Tags: java, restfb

i have been trying to figure out how to use `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=[%22coffee%22]&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token=%token_here%` in restfb and i just keep failing, that's what i tried so far.

```
    String token = "token";
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.LATEST);
    Connection<Place> publicSearch =
              facebookClient.fetchConnection("search", Place.class,
                Parameter.with("q", "coffee"), Parameter.with("type", "place"));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `failing` ?

Comment: you use type "place" in the restfb call and "adinterest" in the url above. Maybe you should check this